# binomial correlation?

Tags: r, regression, binomial-distribution, predictor

I am interested in testing for a correlation between two variables, both of which are binomial.  I guess this is equivalent to a Model II regression where both variables are binomial.  Ideally I want to use R to fit a model of the form

cbind(y1,y2) ~ cbind(x1,x2)

Is this possible?  If not, is there another solution?  I sense this is not such an unusual requirement but have so far struggled to find anything useful on the web.

Comment: I'm a bit confused by this.  In your question you say you have 2 variables, but in your pseudocode you have 4.  Can you please elaborate a bit on what data you have?

Comment: What do you mean by the code using cbind? What are the y1,y2,x1,X2? How are they related?

Comment: I have a large series of observations (actually non-overlapping windows of genomic sequences).  In each window I generate two counts for each of two comparisons, i.e. y1, y2 and x1, x2.  I want to test whether the ratios y1:y2 and x1:x2 covary.  I cannot reasonably use straight ratios because the numbers are often small (< 10).  Ideally, therefore I want to use a binomial function for both predictor and response.

Answer (score 0):

You could perform the classic [Chi Square test of Independence](http://www.r-tutor.com/elementary-statistics/goodness-fit/chi-squared-test-independence) using the MASS library in R. This is not exactly what you ask, which is, what the correlation between multiple dichotomous variables is. However, without more information, I am making some assumptions of what you want to find. I am guessing you may be interested in if these variables are related, in that one level of X is more likely to occur with one level of Y, which this test will provide a null hypothesis test for.

Comment: Many thanks for this idea.  To be clearer, my data comprise about 8,000 rows with variables a1, a2, b1, b2, c, d, e.  The a and b variables need to be fitted as binomials [i.e. cbind(a1,a2) and cbind(b1,b2)].  Both a and b vary hugely (from a1+a2 = 5 up to a1+a2 = 2000.  a1+a2 does not necessarily equal b1 + b2 and can be very different.  Ideally, while I am happy to start with cbind(a1,a2) ~cbind(b1,b2), I would eventually like to be able to fit a multiple regression of the form cbind(a1,a2) ~cbind(b1,b2) + c + d + e.  Does this make more sense?

Comment: Perhaps the point-biserial correlation is what you are after